# XSLT 2.0 Getting attribute by String

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello i want to parameterize the Attributes in an external XML File.
My first Approach is to get read the attributes from a string but i can't read the Attribute value from the string which contanins the Name of the Attribute...
Is there any Solution ???

Example:

### Data.xml:

`<data attrib1="firstattrb1" attrib2="secondattrb1"/>`
`<data attrib1="firstattrb2" attrib2="secondattrb2"/>`

---

### Configure.xml:

### `<ReadAttrib>attrib1</ReadAttrib>`

I want to read only the Attribute that i can write in the configure.xml

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your question is. What would be the expected result in your example?

Comment: I want to read the Attribute which name is written in the config.XML from the data.XML (for example i want to read the attrib1 from data)

Comment: I want write a configure File to read some attributes

Comment: My Goal is that i defined a String like "My $attrib1 is my first Attribute" and i want to interpolate $attrib1 as the Attribute attrib1 from the current node...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a key `<xsl:key name="att-by-name" match="data/@*" use="local-name()"/>` you can use `key('att-by-name', document('Configure.xml')//ReadAttrib)` to find the attributes of the name given in the `ReadAttrib` element.